# EXT:Form - Get layout field from content object data

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to get the layout field of the content object data inside an ext:form content element, to add a css class if a specific layout has been chosen. But nether the content object data is added to the fluid template (`typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Controller/FormFrontendController.php:73`) nor the frame container from fluid_styled_content is rendered for this element.
My layout field is configured like this:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content {
    layout {
        types.form_formframework {
            addItems {
                200 = Blue Form
            }

            removeItems = 1,2,3
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to add a new layout field to the form configuration itself:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      ########### FORMEDITOR CONFIGURATION ###########
      prototypes:
        standard:
          ########### DEFAULT FORM ELEMENT DEFINITIONS ###########
          formElementsDefinition:
            Form:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  9000:
                    identifier: 'layout'
                    group: select
                    templateName: 'Inspector-SingleSelectEditor'
                    label: 'Layout'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.layout'
                    selectOptions:
                      0:
                        value:
                        label: Normal
                      1:
                        value: form--blue
                        label: Blau
```

This works great in the backend but is leading to an `The options "properties" were not allowed` error in the frontend as properties for the form element are hardcoded in `typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Model/FormDefinition.php:382`.

Any ideas how to add a layout selection here? Best would be on the content element, as this would allow me to use the same form configuration with different layouts instead off making a duplicate form configuration which only distinguish in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content object data is available in the Generic-Template from fluid_styled_content. Here you can check if the Ctype is 'form_formframework' and wrapping the form with your css class.

```
<f:if condition="{content}">
<f:then>
    {content -> f:format.raw()}
</f:then>
<f:else>
    <f:if condition="{data.CType} == 'form_formframework'">
        <f:then>
            <div class="{data.layout}">
                <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.{data.CType}.20" data="{data}" table="tt_content"/>
            </div>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.{data.CType}.20" data="{data}" table="tt_content"/>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

We can add the fluid template layout like this({f:if(condition:'{data.layout}',then:'blue')}), in to default fluid_style_content/Resource/Private/Layouts/default.html (we Can override the fluid template in our site template) - without thinking for override the finisher and Flexform values of form:

```
<f:if condition="{data.CType} == 'form_formframework'">
    <f:then>
        <section id="c{data.uid}" class="form-section {f:if(condition:'{data.layout}',then:'blue')}">
            <f:if condition="{data._LOCALIZED_UID}">
                <a id="c{data._LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>
            </f:if>
            <f:render section="Before" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="DropIn/Before/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="Header" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="Header/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="Main" optional="true" />
            <f:render section="Footer" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="Footer/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="After" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="DropIn/After/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
        </section>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-{data.frame_class} frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout}{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
            <f:if condition="{data._LOCALIZED_UID}">
                <a id="c{data._LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>
            </f:if>
            <f:render section="Before" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="DropIn/Before/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="Header" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="Header/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="Main" optional="true" />
            <f:render section="Footer" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="Footer/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
            <f:render section="After" optional="true">
                <f:render partial="DropIn/After/All" arguments="{_all}" />
            </f:render>
        </div>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

I hope it helpful to all!